# ERROR Could not find or parse valid build output file

Tags: android-studio, cordova

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weg65.png)

```
[cordova] ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'C:\Users\55819\Desktop\repos\MobileApp\plugins\cordova-plugin-firebasex\src\android\colors.xml' -> 'C:\Users\55819\Desktop\repos\MobileApp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml'
[ERROR] Could not find or parse valid build output file.

        Tried the following paths:
        - C:\Users\55819\Desktop\repos\MobileApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output.json
        - C:\Users\55819\Desktop\repos\MobileApp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output-metadata.json
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem ?